# One of my ASP.NET Web API's is not showing / available

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a **ASP.NET Web API** solution that contains definitions for several controllers. Recently one of my **ASP.NET Web API**'s has stopped working properly. When I launch my project in *Visual Studio* the *Help* page no longer shows any entries for one of my API's despite showing all the others.

The API cannot be invoked either (I thought it was just the *Help* page not rendering properly, but it looks like the API has disappeared). The API's URL is not available.

When I step through the code of the *Help* page it looks as if the **GlobalConfiguration.Configuration** property doesn't contain an entry for this particular API.

- Why would an API suddenly disappear? This was all working until recently and I had unit tests around it so it was definitely working.
- It's not just disappeared from the Help file (yes I have XML documentation turned on and all other APIs are documented) but the endpoint itself is no longer available either.

When I launch the project, it's as if the API never existed. It cannot be invoked and it's not in the Help documentation, despite all the source code being present and it having previously worked.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage IsRequestAuthenticatedTest()
    {
        base.LogMessage(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}", GetType().Name, "IsRequestAuthenticatedTest"));

        try
        {
            bool result;

            //do some stuff here

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(result ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.LogException(ex);
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you put attribute correctly on the specified method?

Comment: do you have source code for demonstration?

Comment: I've decorated the method with the HttpGet attribute

Comment: Updated with example source code.